# Would I need to use threads for this?

Tags: java, multithreading

Currently, the output of this program is

`Hi
Hola
Ciao
Bonjour
Guten tag
How do you say hi in English?
How do you say hi in Spanish?
How do you say hi in Italian?
How do you say hi in French?
How do you say hi in German?`

Which is what I expected, but my intention is for the output to be more like this:

`How do you say hi in English?
Hi
How do you say hi in Spanish?
Hola
How do you say hi in Italian?
Ciao
How do you say hi in French?
Bonjour
How do you say hi in German?
Guten tag`

My prediction is that I've got to make two threads in order to do this? I'm not to sure how to use threads, but I just want to make sure that threads are what I've got to research next in order to figure out how to do what I want to do. This is just an example, my actual code is a bit more complicated and I feel like this example is an easier way to understand my intentions.

Ok, so here's my code:

```js
package test;

public class Class {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    sayHiLanguages();
    howToSayHi();
  }

  public static void sayHiLanguages() {
    sleepThread(1);
    System.out.println("Hi");
    sleepThread(1);
    System.out.println("Hola");
    sleepThread(1);
    System.out.println("Ciao");
    sleepThread(1);
    System.out.println("Bonjour");
    sleepThread(1);
    System.out.println("Guten tag");
  }

  public static void howToSayHi() {
    System.out.println("How do you say hi in English?");
    sleepThread(1);
    System.out.println("How do you say hi in Spanish?");
    sleepThread(1);
    System.out.println("How do you say hi in Italian?");
    sleepThread(1);
    System.out.println("How do you say hi in French?");
    sleepThread(1);
    System.out.println("How do you say hi in German?");
  }

  public static void sleepThread(long time) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(time * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

If you guys could direct me to a good article about threads that would be great!

Comment: This is not a situation that calls for multithreading. Please see the section on multithreading in the SCJP book by Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates.

Comment: Think about the flow of what you want - ask - answer - ask - answer etc.

Comment: As stated above: "I'm not to sure how to use threads, but I just want to make sure that threads are what I've got to research next in order to figure out how to do what I want to do... This is just an example, my actual code is a bit more complicated and I feel like this example is an easier way to understand my intentions. "

Comment: Dang that's a long pdf... I'll try to get information from it as best I can, thanks for the suggestion @user3516726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live the life simple -

```
package test;

public class Class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sayHiAsLanguages();
    }

    public static void sayHiAsLanguages() {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    //Change Thread sleep amount to see delay difference
                    System.out.println("How do you say hi in English?");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Hi");

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("How do you say hi in Spanish?");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Hola");

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("How do you say hi in Italian?");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Ciao");

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("How do you say hi in French?");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Bonjour");

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("How do you say hi in German?");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Guten tag");

                }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to use methods, I would reccomend using two lists and iterating through them.

```
List<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
answers.add("Hi");
answers.add("Hola");
answers.add("Ciao");
answers.add("Bonjour");
answers.add("Guten tag");

List<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
questions.add("How do you say hi in English?");
questions.add("How do you say hi in Spanish?");
questions.add("How do you say hi in Italian?");
questions.add("How do you say hi in French?");
questions.add("How do you say hi in German?");

for(int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(questions[i])
    System.out.println(answers[i])
}
```

If you are going to use this, I would also reccomend creating a method, to add to these lists quickly.

```
addToLists(String question, String answer)
{
    question.add(question); //question.add("How do you say hi in " + question); would make it even easier
    answers.add(answer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for doing this, but since the code I have above is just an example, I can't apply your answer to my code.

Comment: @Kaelinator What exactly are you doing in your code? Can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, here's the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/932X0z7s That is the code after I used ArifMustafa's answer, which solved my problem*10